# Slow Query... Need it faster

Tags: mysql, sql

To explain the query below, you should know that I have three variables for the current user that get used in the query...

`$radius` Preference the user wants to search in

`$lat`    The user's latitude

`$lon`    The user's longitude

The relevant columns in the zipData table are `zipcode` `lon` and `lat`

I have this query which will works fine to report all other users within the desired radius...

```
$query="
    SELECT username FROM zipData,seekers
    WHERE (POW((69.1*(lon-\"$lon\")*cos($lat/57.3)),\"2\")+POW((69.1*(lat-\"$lat\")),\"2\"))<($radius*$radius)
    AND replace(seekers.postal,' ','') = zipData.zipcode;
";
```

I also have this query which returns only specific users meeting certain criteria...

```
$query="
    SELECT * 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT a.username, MATCH(a.highlight) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
        FROM resume_highlights a
        JOIN seekers ON a.username = seekers.username and seekers.resume_status = 1
        HAVING score>0 

            UNION ALL

        SELECT b.username, MATCH(b.skill,b.skill_list) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
        FROM resume_skills b
        JOIN seekers ON b.username = seekers.username and seekers.resume_status = 1
        HAVING score>0 

            UNION ALL

        SELECT c.username, MATCH(c.education_title,c.education_organization) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
        FROM resume_education c
        JOIN seekers ON c.username = seekers.username and seekers.resume_status = 1
        HAVING score>0 

            UNION ALL

        SELECT d.username, MATCH(d.employer_title,d.employer_organization) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
        FROM resume_employer d
        JOIN seekers ON d.username = seekers.username and seekers.resume_status = 1
        HAVING score>0 

            UNION ALL

        SELECT e.username, MATCH(e.volunteer_title,e.volunteer_organization) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
        FROM resume_volunteer e
        JOIN seekers ON e.username = seekers.username and seekers.resume_status = 1
        HAVING score>0 

    ) AS X
    ORDER BY score desc
";
```

both queries work independently; however, every attempt I have made to combine them into one query has resulted in a VERY slow execution time.

## UPDATE

I do have indexes on `seekers.postal` `zipData.lon` and `zipData.lat`. I would have assumed that would do the trick but it didn't. It might just be that I built the query bad so I would like to see how the 2 queries should be combined.

Answer (score 1):

I think this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html) has your answer:

> The best way to improve the performance of SELECT operations is to
>   create indexes on one or more of the columns that are tested in the
>   query. The index entries act like pointers to the table rows, allowing
>   the query to quickly determine which rows match a condition in the
>   WHERE clause, and retrieve the other column values for those rows. All
>   MySQL data types can be indexed.

Comment: I do have indexes on seekers.postal zipData.lon and zipData.lat  I would have assumed that would do the trick but it didn't. It might just be that I built the query bad so I would like to see how the 2 queries in the initial post should be combined.

Comment: Instead of having `having` , I would recommend `where`  which restricts the result set before returning rows.